# FileChooserButton Gtk

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala, filechooser

Can someone tell me what type of signal for `FileChooserButton` I have to use, to get file path by clicking on the actual file in `FileChooserDialog` that was brought up by `FileChooserButton`? I've used both `file_set` and `file_activated` signals but nothing has happened.

I've used an example from Vala language documentation. And I'm not sure whether there should be Open\Cancel buttons in that dialog(See the screenshot below)?

Here is the code, that I've used:

```
Gtk.FileChooserButton file_chooser = new Gtk.FileChooserButton(
        "Select a file",
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN);
file_chooser.set_show_hidden(true);
file_chooser.set_local_only(false);
file_chooser.set_current_folder("/home");   

Gtk.FileFilter filter = new Gtk.FileFilter();
filter.add_mime_type("application/x-shellscript");

file_chooser.set_filter(filter);
file_chooser.file_set.connect(() => {
    string uri = file_chooser.get_uri();
    stdout.printf("Uri: %s", uri);
});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LEHv.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Missing "\n" in your printf, I think

Comment: `file-set` is for when the user clicks Open to choose a file, thus changing the file that the GtkFileChooserButton represents. `file-activated` is for when the user double-clicks a file in a GtkFileChooserWidget; I assume GtkFileChooserDialog and GtkFileChooserButton both that that as clicking Open. [I'm guessing you want `selection-changed`?](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#GtkFileChooser-selection-changed) That is, assuming that I read your question correctly and that you want to be notified when an item on the list is clicked. Did I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! The problem was in missing buttons `Ok\Cancel`, this occurs only in Elementary OS, I believe.

Command:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader':<0>}"` did it's job!
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: File a bug with the Elementary authors? Assuming you are using the latest version of everything...

Comment: @andlabs yes, I've filed a bug. And I update it every day